# Titanium: ImageView for Android that is scrollable horizontal AND vertical

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, titanium, scrollview

I have the following problem by developing an app for Android with Titanium Mobile:

I have an `ImageView` that fills out the complete screen. In this `ImageView` is a picture which is bigger than the `ImageView`; you need to scroll to see all elements of the picture.

How can I create an `ImageView` on `Titanium` that's scrollable on Android (vertical AND horizontal). I've tried to solve this by putting the `ImageView` in a `ScrollView`, but a `ScrollView` on Android only can scroll vertical OR horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You're only option I believe is a web view. Nothing else scrolls both directions.